# Div showing on click, but not hiding on second click with CSS and Jquery, not using buttons, but classes in <li> tages

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide

Here is my code... So firstly if you click menu, the `<ul>` appears, each li has a class assigned, which should then open up a section that slides down, and slide up on click. This is only sliding down at the moment... sad face... Im new to Jquery, so please be gentle... :) ... Also I would prefer not changing too much of my code, as I will probably just get stuck again if I do... if this is possible... thank yoU!!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function() {
      $(".menu-trigger").hide("scale")
      jQuery(".test").slideToggle(900, function ([complete]){
       jQuery(this).toggleClass(".test").css("display");
 }) 
  });
 });
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".bio-button").click(function() {
  jQuery(".bio-content").slideToggle(900, function ([complete]){
   jQuery(this).toggleClass(".bio-content").css("display");
 }) 
  });
 });
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".drums-button").click(function() {
  jQuery(".drums-content").slideToggle(900, function ([complete]){
   jQuery(this).toggleClass(".drums-content").css("display");
 }) 
  });
 });
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".info-button").click(function() {
  jQuery(".info-content").slideToggle(900, function ([complete]){
   jQuery(this).toggleClass(".info-content").css("display");
 }) 
  });
 });
    function changeImage(){
  var ima = document.getElementById("BSlate");
   if (ima.src.match('BIDSlate')){
    (ima.src ="img/BSlate.png").fadeIn(1200);
    }
    else
  (ima.src ="img/BIDSlate.png").fadeIn(1200);
    }
```

```css
.bio-content{
 height:400px;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 width:100%;
 display:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
    }
    .info-content{
 height:800px;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 width:100%;
 display:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
    }
    .drums-content {
 height:400px;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 width:100%;
 display:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
    }
```

```html
<!-------------- MY HTML -------------------->

    <div id="menuwrapper"><!-----------MENU START------------>
 <img id="BSlate" src="img/BSlate.png" style="max-width:100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="test">
     <ul>
         <li class="bio-button">Biography</li>
            <li class="info-button">Info</li>
            <li class="drums-button">Drums</li>
        </ul>
            <div class="bio-content"></div>
            <div class="info-content"></div>
            <div class="drums-content"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="menu-trigger" onclick="changeImage()"><h1 class="menu-button">MENU</h1></span><!-----------END MENU------------>
```

Comment: Why you are repeating `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` with every click binding you can move all bindings in a single block;

Comment: instead of toggling class use toggle directly

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.. kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/26ako4Lp/1/

**jQuery**

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('.test > ul').on('click','li',function(){
    var itm=jQuery(this).attr('class');
  console.log(itm);

  switch(itm){
  case 'bio-button':
  jQuery('.bio-content').slideToggle('slow');
  break;

  case 'info-button':
  jQuery('.info-content').slideToggle('slow');
  break;

  case 'drums-button':
  jQuery('.drums-content').slideToggle('slow');
  break;


  }
});

});
```